# How do I rename my Magikarp?

Tags: magikarp-jump

In Magikarp Jump, the screen when you initially catch and name a Magikarp says the following:

> Give your Magikarp a nickname!
>
> - Maximum 12 characters
> - **Nicknames can be changed at any time**

I've tried checking the records screen, game settings, and town, but I haven't seen any way to change my Magikarp's name.

**How do I change a Magikarp's nickname in Magikarp Jump?**

[image: name your magikarp]

Comment: A lot of things are weirdly hidden away. Like to check which Individual Bonus your Magikarp has, you have to go to the Town, then Records, then Status. Having that (as well as the Rename button) available by tapping the Magikarp's name on the main screen would be much better...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on your trainer profile and scroll to the bottom. You'll have an option to change your Magikarp's nickname there.

[image: trainer profile]

[image: change nickname]

Comment: Did you download the game just for these screenshots?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro yes.